# Remove extra "the"s and improve a sentence

Tags: word-usage, articles

I have the following statement describing a course learning outcome:

> At the end of this course, the students will be able to:
>
> 1. Apply concepts of lighting and illumination technology and show the types of electrical installations and their techniques and the protection systems used in buildings.
> 2. ...

I feel that there are too many the's than is necessary. I also feel that the sentence can be improved. As a non-native speaker, I always struggle with such structures. I deeply appreciate your suggestions and help.

Comment: If you were not aware, you should know that proofreading is explicitly off-topic, as it is subjective, and is rarely applicable to any future visitors. That said, I do not see an excess of *the*s, but would edit to reduce the of *and*s. Please review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster Thank you, now I know. In fact, I encounter too many sentences like this, and fixing just one means to me fixing too many others and really helps. How would you reduce the use of **and**s, BTW? Posting an answer will be appreciated, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> Apply concepts of lighting and illumination technology and show the types of electrical installations and their techniques and the protection systems used in buildings.

I agree that the sentence could be improved, mainly because of the phrase 'and their techniques'. I don't know what 'their' is supposed to relate to. I don't think that 'electrical installations' have techniques.

Let's remove that part to get:

*Apply concepts of lighting and illumination technology and show the types of electrical installations and the protection systems used in buildings.*

That version is okay but I'd remove the plural from 'installations'. You can paraphrase it:

*Apply [some] concepts of lighting and illumination technology and show the [specific] types of electrical installation and the [specific] protection systems used in buildings.*

In my opinion the whole sentence is shoddily constructed but at least its meaning is reasonably clear.

Comment: ,@chaslyfromUK Thank you for the quick answer. By **installations**, I mean the plural, does **installation** do the same? You also didn't mention **the**, can you please elaborate a bit on this? Thanks again.